# Solving $A*X*B = X*C$ with $X$ the only unknown

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I've formulated a problem as above, and wondering if a solution is actually possible.

Dimensionality:

- $A$ is $N \times N$ (known)
- $B$ and $C$ are $N \times 1$ (known)
- $X$ is $N \times N$ (unknown)

Now obviously the problem is very underdetermined, and I am also expecting the solution would involve null space, but I am not worried about this for now as I can add an arbitrary number of observations.

But before I do that, I am just wondering if it is possible in principle to disentangle X from the sandwich it finds itself in?

Comment: Of course, $X=0$ is always a solution. For $A=0$ we can solve it as well, with $Xc=0$. In general, we can solve it by equations in the entries of $X$.

Comment: I should have stipulated, X and A are non-zero. Can you elaborate on your last statement at all?

Comment: [This](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S089396590800013X) paper should answer your question essentially using greg's idea.

Comment: @a.padoan yes, that does look applicable, and with W=0 so I imagine easier to solve... I don't suppose you are familiar with a Matlab implementation? They have a function to solve Sylvester equations of the form AX + XB = C, but the more complicated form of AX + BY = EXF shown in the paper.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer:

1. If $C=\lambda B$ then $XB$ is an eigenvector of $A$ of eigenvalue $\lambda$, you can compute all of them and then define any $X$ that sends $B$ to such eigenvector.
2. Otherwise they are linearly independent, so you can extend them to a base of the whole space. Let $v$ be any $N\times 1$ vector and $w=Av$. Then you can find $X$ such that $XB=v$ and $XC=w$ by defining a linear transformation on the basis we created before (lots of liberty here), any such $X$ is going to be a solution.

Comment: B and C could definitely be mapped by a linear transformation, so I think #1 holds... It is easy enough to compute the eigenvectors of A, but I am a little fuzzy on how to "define any X that sends B to such eigenvector". e.g. How do I pick the right eigenvector?

Comment: any eigenvector would work?

Answer (score 0):

$\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\v{\operatorname{vec}}$Use
a Kronecker product to [flatten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the unknown matrix into a vector
$x=\v(X),\,$ i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\v(AXb) - \v(I_nXc) &= 0 \\
\L((b^T\otimes A)-(c^T\otimes I_n)\R)x &= 0 \\
Mx &= 0 \\
}$$
Therefore $x$ lies in the nullspace of $M$ and can be calculated in terms of an arbitrary vector $w$ and the pseudoinverse $M^+$
$$\eqalign{
x &= \L(I_{n^2}-M^+M\R)w \\
X &= {\rm reshape}(x,n,n)
}$$
This isn't a unique solution but a whole family of solutions determined by the $w$ vector.